# Deploy JAVA app on heroku using Maven version error

Tags: java, maven, heroku, heroku-toolbelt, heroku-cli

I am trying to deploy my JAVA app on the heroku.
I have my pom.xml with the versions configured correctly as below.

```
<plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.heroku.sdk</groupId>
                <artifactId>heroku-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <appName>kreatorbackendservices</appName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                  <version>3.1.2</version>
                  <executions>
                      <execution>
                          <phase>package</phase>
                          <goals><goal>copy</goal></goals>
                          <configuration>
                              <artifactItems>
                                  <artifactItem>
                                      <groupId>com.github.jsimone</groupId>
                                      <artifactId>webapp-runner</artifactId>
                                      <version>9.0.30.0</version>
                                      <destFileName>webapp-runner.jar</destFileName>
                                  </artifactItem>
                              </artifactItems>
                          </configuration>
                      </execution>
                  </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
```

My maven build is successful without any warnings about the version.
However, when i try to push the code into heroku master i am getting the below error related to version.

Am i overseeing something?

```
Total 176 (delta 47), reused 158 (delta 41), pack-reused 0
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Java app detected
remote: -----> Installing JDK 1.8... done
remote: -----> Installing Maven 3.6.2... done
remote: -----> Executing Maven
remote:        $ mvn -DskipTests clean dependency:list install
remote:        [INFO] Scanning for projects...
remote:        [ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
remote:        [FATAL] 'build.plugins.plugin.(groupId:artifactId)' version of a plugin must be defined.  @ line 238, column 12
remote:         @
remote:        [ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
remote:        [ERROR]
remote:        [ERROR]   The project com.kreator.rest:kreatorRestServices:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT (/tmp/build_7ac5dae3be413ab02bca5ab99dfc0242/pom.xml) has 1 error
remote:        [ERROR]     'build.plugins.plugin.(groupId:artifactId)' version of a plugin must be defined.  @ line 238, column 12
remote:        [ERROR]
remote:        [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
remote:        [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
remote:        [ERROR]
remote:        [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
remote:        [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
remote:
remote:  !     ERROR: Failed to build app with Maven
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! If you can't find the issue in application code,
remote:        please submit a ticket so we can help: https://help.heroku.com/
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Java app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to kreatorbackendservices.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/kreatorbackendservices.git
```

Comment: What version of maven are you running locally?

Comment: @Malax I running it on Maven 3.5.4, thats the one i have it installed in my system